# append IP address to char* using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, append, ip

I am new in C++. I want to append `IP address` to the already existing `char*`

can someone please tell me how to do this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: the answer is ... **you don't do this in C++** Instead of `char*`, you use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for string manipulation. C-style strings (`char*`) are sometimes a necessary evil when dealing with third-partly libraries and C code. Also, don't use `#define` for defining literals.

Comment: Note that `"\x42\x01"` is not a string of hexadecimal digits; it's the same as `{ 0x42, 0x01, 0x0 }`, which is the same as `{ 66, 1, 0 }`. That is, it's a "string" that contains those numbers, not the hexadecimal representation of those numbers.

Comment: To put it another way: you shouldn't involve `printf` or any other conversion to strings. You want to take apart the IP address into bytes and append those *numbers*, not their textual representation.

Comment: what was the intent on the command? did you mean to add numbers as string in the `char*` or did you actually mean to have binary data? Also do you want to have binary data in your command (representing the IP address) or do you want to have the actual IP address in CIDR format?

Comment: it seems to me that your `char *` should really more be a `char[]` in that case (if following C), but I would then not use a string to model it in C++, but instead use a `std::vector<char>` since you want to append at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you use c++ rather than c this becomes easier. If you use [boost::asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio) (soon to be part of the standard) its even easier.

```
const std::string IP = "169.254.1.34"; // don't use #define to define constants
auto address = boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4( IP );

std::stringstream command;
command << "\x42\x01\x00\x82\x00\x08\x10\x1f\x00\x00\x0d\x18";
auto decimal = htonl( address.to_uint() );
command.write( (char*)decimal, sizeof(decimal) );
```

Comment: Linking boost just for that seems a bit... overreacted, don't you think?

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy Yes but presumably he's going to be doing other networking stuff which is much easier with asio than raw sockets. Also I think there's no linking involved as asio is header only.

Comment: Guy is a rookie. Boost::asio API isn't for beginners... But yeah, it is definitely better than raw sockets, if one can actually make use of it. For him, I think, this is too much of a step to be done at once. Being 5yr c++ developer, I'm still sorta scared of using Boost because of the early experience I had when I wasn't ready for it...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your task is to implement some sort of binary protocol of communication, which involves sending IP address as 4-byte value within a command. To do that the proper way, I'd create a struct that contains both IP address (as unsigned int), and the suffix of the command. This gives you more flexibility on the construction of packages. Pretty much, like this:

```
template <int suffix_size>
struct Packet
{   
    uint32_t ip_binary_;
    char data_[suffix_size];

    template<int suffix_size>
    Packet<suffix_size>(std::string IP, const char* command_byte_array)
    {
        ip_binary_ = inet_addr(IP.c_str());
        memcpy(data_, command_byte_array, suffix_size);
    }

    template<int suffix_size>
    const char* pack() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(this);
    }

    template<int suffix_size>
    int size() const { return suffix_size + sizeof(uint32_t); }
};
```

With this example, you can define both size and IP address separately. Also, method pack() will do the packing automatically.

(didn't test the code, probably there'll be some errors, but I hope that you'll get the point)

EDIT: overall, if you are actually implementing a protocol, make sure that your command descriptions are as explicit as possible. Using char* and its offsets to put data there... It works, but makes code unreadable.

From this example you can expand on, for example -

```
struct SomeCmdPacket: Packet<SomeCmdPacketSize>
{
    ...
    SomeCmdPacket(std::string IP):
    Packet<SomeCmdPacketSize>(IP, "\x00*put your command here*");
    {

    }
};
```